# isomorphic code for native node.js and browser crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, isomorphic-javascript, webcrypto-api, mjs

There is the [isomorphic-webcrypto](https://github.com/kevlened/isomorphic-webcrypto) that pretends doing that but doesn't : it builds separate build for each target.

There is the [noble-crypto](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-ed25519/blob/master/index.ts#L831) way to do it, but it's based on if-else conditions and fails if I want an isomorphic mjs code.

Finally, there is the [eval require way](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/276#issuecomment-695820218) way to pass-through bundler, but node fails to use it in mjs.

In brief :

```js
const crypto = require("crypto"); // work only in node.js but not in mjs file.
const crypto = eval(`require("crypto")`); // pass-thru bundler, then work only in node.js but not in mjs file.
window.crypto; // work only in browser
import * as crypto from "crypto"; // could work from both but must be at top level of a module, so it can't be a conditional import.
```

I would like to use native crypto in node.js and in browser, in an isomorphic way, to be able to use native import mjs in node and browser transparently.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Alright.  Ready for something ugly?  :-)  Behold, my latest hackjob… IsomorphicCyrpto.js:

```
export default
  globalThis.crypto ||
  (await import('node:crypto')).default.webcrypto
;
```

This works in Node.js v16 in module mode ([`"type": "module"` in package.json](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type), or equivalent CLI args), and will probably work with your bundler too… but who knows.  ;-)  Anyone using this code snippet should test thoroughly on whatever platforms they want to use it on.

In a nutshell:

- We use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), which represents `global` under Node.js, `window` for most browser contexts, and could perhaps even be a Worker context.
- We first check to see if `crypto` is a thing.  If it is, we're probably on a browser, and can just use that directly.
- If `crypto` is not a thing, we're probably on Node.js and we need to import the module.
- Because this is done dynamically, we need a [dynamic `import()`](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import) rather than a true `import`.
- `import()` is async and returns a Promise.  But hey, it's all good, because [top-level `await`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/34558) is a thing in Node.js now!

To then use the module:

```
import crypto from './lib/IsomorphicCrypto.js';
console.log( crypto.randomUUID() );
```

Uggggly, but works for now.  Hopefully, someone comes up with a better solution, or Node.js and browser contexts converge on naming in the future.

Comment: after all of the horrible other attempts in the JS world to get isomorphic modules this seems comparatively beautiful

Comment: @stealthwang Thank you for commenting on this... I was just looking for something like this again last night, and forgot all about it.  :-)

Comment: I also just discovered if you're using a recent enough version of node that `globalThis.crypto` will work as an alias to the `node:crypto` module

Answer (score 0):

In Node version 20 & up there is a global `crypto` object that provides the webcrypto API that you needed to manually import in earlier versions:

```
globalThis.crypto === require('node:crypto').webcrypto
```

So the code:

```
globalThis.crypto.randomUUID()
```

Would work the same in the browser & in Node with no imports and no special tooling.